# Is this implementation use HBOS mathematic?

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering

I'm experimenting with an *unsupervised statistical-based outlier detection* so-called **XBOS** on top of the [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html) clustering algorithm. It is claimed that XBOS generates *outlier scores* as [HBOS](https://www.dfki.de/fileadmin/user_upload/import/6431_HBOS-poster.pdf) does. I'm trying to understand math is used behind the implementation entirely. To the best of my knowledge, it has four functions inside the [xbos-class](/questions/tagged/xbos-class), and I assume that the implementer tried the HBOS formula, but I'm not sure that's what I raised here.
I changed slightly the code due to it was scripted in class and method form adjust keep functions for better understanding:

```
n_clusters=n
effectiveness=e
max_iter=m
kmeans = {}
cluster_score = {}

def fit( data):
    length = len(data)
    for column in data.columns:
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters,max_iter=max_iter)
        kmeans[column]=kmeans
        kmeans.fit(data[column].values.reshape(-1,1))
        assign = pd.DataFrame(kmeans.predict(data[column].values.reshape(-1,1)),columns=['cluster'])
        cluster_score=assign.groupby('cluster').apply(len).apply(lambda x:x/length)
        ratio=cluster_score.copy()
    
        sorted_centers = sorted(kmeans.cluster_centers_)
        max_distance = ( sorted_centers[-1] - sorted_centers[0] )[ 0 ]
    
        for i in range(n_clusters):
            for k in range(n_clusters):
                if i != k:
                    dist = np.abs(kmeans.cluster_centers_[i] - kmeans.cluster_centers_[k])/max_distance
                    effect = ratio[k]*(1/pow(effectiveness,dist))
                    cluster_score[i] = cluster_score[i]+effect
                    
        cluster_score[column] = cluster_score
                
def predict( data):
    length = len(data)
    score_array = np.zeros(length)
    for column in data.columns:    # ============> here they applied summation Sigma
        kmeans = kmeans[ column ]
        cluster_score = cluster_score[ column ]
        
        assign = kmeans.predict( data[ column ].values.reshape(-1,1) )
        #print(assign)
        
        for i in range(length):
            score_array[i] = score_array[i] + math.log10( cluster_score[assign[i]] ) #====> here they applied logarithm
        
    return score_array
```

To the best of my knowledge, HBOS generate bin-width histograms statically/dynamically. For multivariate cases having `d` features, individual histogram density is computed for each feature and then summed up to derive a conclusion. They use a simple formula for this:

[image: img]

So it means they calculate log(1/p) for each feature/column in the dataframe. So mainly my questions are (compare to HBOS):

- **What is the mathematical mechanism behind XBOS using clustering?**
- **How does calculate the width of histograms in XBOS?**

According to [Github](https://github.com/Kanatoko/XBOS-anomaly-detection) Repo, It uses a similar mechanism to generate histograms and collect clustering info (e.g. `effectiveness`, `cluster_score`, `cluster_centers`, `max_distance`). Especially `dist` & `effect` during fitting KMeans on each column and sum them up for better clustering the sense of *outlier detection*.

- Would you explain which math formula has been used for this in the 2nd function, `def fit()`?
- Is it the same as the HBOS formula?

```
for i in range(self.n_clusters):
    for k in range(self.n_clusters):
         if i != k:
               dist = np.abs(kmeans.cluster_centers_[i] - kmeans.cluster_centers_[k])/max_distance
                effect = ratio[k]*(1/pow(self.effectiveness,dist))
                cluster_score[i] = cluster_score[i]+effect
```

At the end of the 3rd function, `def predict()`, It can be seen that it is applied logarithm on data and return score_array. I try to understand this part of the codes too:

```
for i in range(length):
                score_array[i] = score_array[i] + math.log10( cluster_score[assign[i]] ) #Apply logaritm
```

Any help understanding the mathematics and clustering strategy in current implementation will be appreciated.

Comment: If you deemphasize Python, and concentrate on the math, perhaps you could ask at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ,  But they don't like things to be code-centric on that board.

Comment: the problem with this quesiton is that it is very niche: either you know the topics, or you simply cannot even understand the question. Maths, algorithms, python, ML, the question mixes all these topics! Perhaps you would get more answer if you could simplify the question. I tried reading your question a few times, but XBOS/HBOS etc is still not clearly defined in my mind...

One thing I noted that I am not sure if you are familiar with, the HBOS looks like an entropy measure. Good luck with your research!

Comment: @MarineGalantin I already studied [HBOS](https://www.dfki.de/fileadmin/user_upload/import/6431_HBOS-poster.pdf) & later [XBOS](https://github.com/Kanatoko/XBOS-anomaly-detection) implementation. Both are referenced in the post to avoid the long post and I highlighted my questions related to its implementation within **bold** form. I want to understand the maths behind *XBOS*, which is scripted in 4 pythonic functions. I don't think I mixed anything with ML, but I'm sorry for framing the lousy question. I also commented on each function in the code my understanding.

Comment: I was wondering if you could help with code reviewing math-wisely in implementation.  I'm afraid it's not *entropy measure* but *Histogram-based anomaly detection* using clustering. Anyway, likewise with yours!!